# Find function in VBA returns Nothing

Tags: excel, vba, find

I have a function that receives a name (String variable "name"), and needs to find that name in a list (Range variable "list") and perform other non relevant operations in that list. The Find function is not being able to find "name" in "list", which is strange, because trying a single case (the first Print) outputs True, but using the Find function returns Nothing.

```
Debug.Print list(22) = name //this prints True

Dim result As Range
Set result = list.Find(name)
Debug.Print result //this generates Error 91 Variable not set
Debug.Print result.Value //this also generates Error 91 Variable not set
```

The only caveat is that the Strings being compared include double quotes, which tend to be tricky, but I've checked and in all cases the one being used is Chr(34)

Comment: Specify the other parameters of `Find`:  specifically `LookIn`, and `LookAt`.

Comment: I have had many troubles with Find. It has trouble with merged cells, numbers formatted as text, dates, and is painfully literal when comparing text. You noted that double quotes can be tricky. You should also be careful of spaces, line breaks, tab characters. They may be written differently in Excel and VBA, which makes them not match despite being Copy-Pasted from one to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Adding LookIn and LookAt parameters worked:

```
Set result = list.Find(name, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
```